# How to properly export/import an object in this nodeJS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodeJS project where I have this file GameState.js with this structure:

```
const GameState = function(socket){
  this.socket = socket
  //quite a large constructor so I removed most of it
};

//defining all the prototype methods
GameState.prototype.getSocket = function() {
  return this.socket
}

module.exports = GameState;
```

I'm able use this GameScreen constructor in my gamescreen.js file, by having the two scripts in my gamescreen.html file like this:

```
<script src = "gamestate.js"></script>
<script src = "gamescreen.js"></script>
```

So for getting GameState into gamescreen.js I actually don't need the module.exports, it's even giving me a (non-breaking) ReferenceError when I use the app, which is quite annoying.

However with my current structure I can't remove this module.exports as I also have a test file (using jest) where I import GameState with require like this:

```
const GameState = require("../scripts/gamestate.js");

//the tests here...
```

So my question is: How do I get GameState in both gamescreen.js and gamestate.test.js, without having the ReferenceError? Right now it's all working, but it's not very optimal to get an error in the console when running the app.

EDIT: A better way to formulate this question might be: I have a module GameState defined with module.exports, now how do I get it in gamescreen.js (the client-side), without losing the ability to import it with require(...) in a test file?

Comment: `<script>`? That doesn't look like a nodejs project

Comment: Use the UMD pattern, or a build tool, or ES6 modules

Comment: @Bergi I have the scripts there as this gamescreen.js file is mainly client side, but it still interacts with websockets from the server side so that's why it's in my node project

Comment: Doesn't matter how the server it interacts with is implemented, it's still a clientside script.

Comment: You can (and should) use ES6 modules. It's a standard that works without unnecessary module systems. P. S. Why didn't you use a class instead of a constructor function?

Comment: @VladyslavYukhanov it was not a conscious choice. This is an old assignment I did for a course where it was a requirement to define objects like that. I'm looking back at it now and trying to improve things, so I'll probably start using classes too. As for the ES6 modules, I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the error by simply wrapping the module.exports in a try catch block like this:

```
try {
  module.exports = GameState;
} catch(error) {
  console.log("didn't work")
}
```

When I run it in the browser it functions normally and prints: "didn't work" and when I run my tests with npm test, the tests work too.

It might not be the prettiest fix, so any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: As suggested: Use the UMD pattern, or a build tool, or ES6 modules. (Or even a mix of them)